# How to disable MDX in Docusaurus

Tags: docusaurus

I have an existing site that uses Markdown and has HTML snippets but do not want them to be treated as MDX. How can I disable MDX entirely for now?

Comment: I'm migrating a legacy wiki with hundreds of pages that have HTML snippets. If Docusaurus has been updated to include this functionality since the question was asked originally I would appreciate a response.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that is possible to disable the MDX, but here's an alternative.

Put your `HTML` snippets inside a `jfx` [code block](https://docusaurus.io/docs/markdown-features/code-blocks). For example:

````
```jsx title="A Great Title (optional)"

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <title>HTML Tutorial</title>
  <body>

    <h1>This is a heading</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph.</p>

  </body>
</html> 

```
````

This will produce

[image: Results]

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply - This would require me to modify all of my markdown, but is something at least I could try. I was really just hoping for a "disable" MDX compiling because I can't even view my pages until all of the code snippets compile without errors

Comment: I searched a way to disable the `MDX` and a way to make the docusaurus ignore the errors, no luck... The last idea is to *comment* your `HTML` with the comment block  `<!-- 'the snippets' -->`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can checkout out here to config docusaurus.config file :[markdown config](https://docusaurus.io/docs/api/docusaurus-config#markdown)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35345045)